# Workaround for overriding a limited set of methods of an interface

Tags: java, design-patterns, object-oriented, object-oriented-design

I have an interface that has ~30 methods and has two different implementations.

I am trying to create another implementation which will have some custom logic and at times it will call one of those existing implementations depending on some conditions.

The issue is that I only want this behavior for a subset of methods, let's say 10 methods.

```
public interface ITest {

void method1(Param1 param1);
void method2(Param2 param2);

}

public class TestImpl1 implements ITest {
void method1(Param1 param1){
//
}
void method2(Param2 param2){
//
}
}
```

Let's say, I only want to override method1 in the new implementation and that could call existing implementation in some of the cases.

Delegating the call from a new interface to existing one for method2 seems like a way but I am not sure if that's the best option. Any idea would be appreciated to make it look cleaner.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that your class would have part own implementation, part `Impl1` and part `Impl2`? Like if you were to create a diamond with multiple inheritance?

Answer (score 1):

Will code call the methods you're not implementing? If not, you can just throw [`UnsupportedOperationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html). Since it's a `RuntimeException`, it will still compile. If code *is* calling the methods you don't want to implement, you can automatically implement those methods and delegate to an existing implementation using [`InvocationHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler.html). This may be convenient because your interface is particularly long. For example:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;

public class TestImpl1 implements InvocationHandler {
    private final ITest delegate1;
    private final ITest delegate2;

    public TestImpl1(ITest delegate1, ITest delegate2) {
        this.delegate1 = delegate1;
        this.delegate2 = delegate2;
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) {
        if (method.getName.equals("method1") {
            // choose delegate 1 or 2
            if (...) {
                method.invoke(delegate1, args);
            } else {
                method.invoke(delegate2, args);
            }
        } else {
            // for all other methods, delegate to delegate1
            method.invoke(delegate1, args);
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like so:

```
ITest delegate1 = ...
ITest delegate2 = ...
// instantiate a proxy
ITest testImpl1 = (ITest) Proxy.newProxyInstance(ITest.class.getClassLoader(),
            new Class[] { ITest.class },
            new TestImpl1(delegate1, delegate2));
// use
testImpl1.method1(...)
testImpl1.method2(...)
```